# Codeigniter + Memcache is dropping sessions, but evictions are sitting at 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, memcached

I'm working on a website, using PHP and Codeigniter, configured to use Memcache for session storage. I'm using [this library](https://bitbucket.org/xperez/core-session-storage-for-codeigniter) to replace Codeigniter's built-in session storage in order to use PHP's native sessions, and then I configured PHP to use Memcache to store session data. (I originally had the library connecting to Memcache directly, but I couldn't get the cookie to persist the way I wanted.) So it's all set up and working. But there's a problem, obviously. For some reason, the site will, at unpredictable intervals, drop user sessions. It's very erratic and hard to duplicate, and I'm not sure if it's losing the session entirely or just losing all the userdata - for my application, there's no difference visible to the user. It's definitely not related to inactivity - I've seen it happen overnight, but I've had reports of it occurring after sitting at one page for only a couple of minutes, too.

**Now, I know what you're thinking. Read this before you answer.** My first thought was, oh, Memcache is running out of space and it's doing its eviction thing. So I checked, and that doesn't seem to be the problem. Memcache is sitting pretty with tons of free space, and evictions are holding steady at zero. Unfortunately, that leaves me with no idea what's going on. Has anyone experienced this kind of problem?